# Integrating VTK into Windows Forms Application

Tags: c++, winforms, vtk

I am trying to create an application that merges both, forms and the VTK library. I am able to use VTK in a new window created from a winforms window and display information in there, but I would also like to be able to integrate VTK in a panel-like object to merge all the VTK components in one simple winforms form.

If I am not beign explicit enough, please let me know and I'll try to be more specific.

Thank you very much for your help.